# what does !! do in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using some code that uses this syntax (restful authentication).

```
def logged_in?
  !!current_user()
end
```

Tried googling for this but it just seems to ignore "!!", will accept an answer that can tell me how to find info about searching for strings such as !! in google.

Comment: the "!" character is called a bang.  googling for "ruby double bang" turns up some good results.

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot about the bang term for exclamation marks.  Is bang an American term?  We don't really use it in UK, only ever heard of it in software terms.  Another example is C#, which in UK would generally be called C hash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does !! mean in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: this code does also provide us an example of not very self-documenting code :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's double negation. The first `!` converts it to `false` if `current_user` is not `nil` or `false`. After that it converts it to `true`. So the result is always a boolean value and not the value of `current_user`. The result is always `true` if `current_user` is not `false` or `nil`. Otherwise it's `false`.

Comment: E.g., it converts a truthy or falsey value into a genuinely boolean value (truthy => `true`, falsey => `false`). See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310344

Comment: This is very handy for forcing an arbitrary value to a simple boolean.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, several people really answered the question, and very quickly too. 

I have selected the most popular answer as the correct answer, hope this is agreeable.

Answer (score 8):

It's the negation operator, `!`, twice. This gives a value that has the same truth value, but is explicitly only a boolean.

In Ruby, there are many values that are considered to be "true" (anything besides `false` and `nil`), and a couple that are considered to be "false" (both `false` and `nil`). The first negation converts all true values to `false`, and all false values to `true`. The second negation then reverses that, leaving you with a value that has the same truth value as the original, but only allowing the actual values `true` or `false`.

This can be helpful if you don't want people  to use `logged_in?` as a way to access the current user, but instead you want it to just return a boolean.

It it equivalent to the more explicit and verbose:

```
def logged_in?
  if current_user()
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This article seems to use the same code:

http://toolmantim.com/articles/bangbang_your_nil_is_dead

Basically, it looks like it's just meant to apply the not (!) operator twice -- essentially forcing the method to return true or false instead of true, false, or nil.

That is, if `@current_user` is nil, calling

```
def logged_in?
  @current_user()
end
```

will return nil.  Changing it to (single bang)

```
def logged_in?
  !@current_user()
end
```

will return true, and changing further to (double bang)

```
def logged_in?
  !!@current_user()
end
```

will return false -- which is more applicable (and usable) than nil.

Another way to write it would be:

```
def logged_in?
  !@current_user().nil?
end
```

but that doesn't cover the case when `@current_user` is false, and I think the `!!` is nicer to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The blog post covers it:

http://toolmantim.com/articles/bangbang_your_nil_is_dead