# What is the usage of "!!" (negating twice)?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double Negation in C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code)

Let's say:

```
bool var = !!true;
```

It will assign "true" to the variable. Seems useless, but I was looking at Visual Studio's definition of "assert", and it is:

```
#define assert(_Expression) (void)( (!!(_Expression)) || (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#_Expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), __LINE__), 0) )
```

Why does it negate the "_Expression" twice?

I wonder that they want to force the "!" operator to be called (in the case it is overloaded), but that doesn't seem to be a good reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310344/why-use-when-converting-int-to-bool

Comment: A common reason would be to get a `0` or `1` from an expression that may have some other true value.  I don't think that applies here.

Comment: Something the duplicate doesn't mention, but was asked here: It's useless if you're converting to `bool`. But once upon a time we had to use integer types to store booleans in C, and this was a useful way to avoid values other than `1` or `0`.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is closed, although it's not an exact duplicate. The *real* reason the above code uses `!!expr` rather than `bool(expr)` is to [**avoid microsoft's own stupid warning C4800**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx). The `!=0` trick doesn't work in generic contexts.

Comment: I had this exact same question once I read the definition for assert in VS. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!!` guarantees that the result will end up as a 1 or a 0, rather than just the value of `_Expression` or 0.  In C, it's unlikely to matter, but in C++ I think it turns the result of the expression into a `bool` type, which might be useful in some cases.  If you did have some API that required a literal 1 or 0 be passed to it, using `!!` would be a way to make it happen.

Answer (score 4):

**It's possible** that you might want an int variable that's either `1` or `0`.

So you can't for example pass a `5`, instead the double negation would turn that `5` into a `1`.

Also, have a look at how `TRUE` is defined:

```
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE                1
#endif
```

Therefore, an expression like:

```
int x = 5;
if ( x == TRUE )
{
   //....
}
```

would not pass, whereas

```
if ( x )
{
   //....
}
```

would.

Answer (score 1):

Its use is to make sure the value is either 0 or 1. I think it's superfluous with C++'s bool type.