# Determine if int is not 0 with no if statements

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-manipulation

The title is a little misleading, but I don't know what else to call it. I have an array consisting of 2  values:
`int array [2];`

One of the values will contain 0 and the other value won't contain 0. Without the use of an if statement and most preferably, no boolean expressions, I want to determine if `array[0];` contains a 0 or not. If it doesn't contain 0, it should return 1, otherwise it should return 0.

I have tried dividing the first value by itself but a Division By Zero error can occur, and I have no other alternatives to my problem.

The format I am aiming for is like this:

`array[check if zero index is 0];`

EDIT: Examples of this are:

```
array[0] = 20; 
array[1] = 0;
array[check if zero index is 0]; // index is 1

array[0] = 0; 
array[1] = 73;
array[check if zero index is 0]; // index is 0;
```

Comment: Why are you interested in this? just for the fun of it, or for a specific purpose?

Comment: You can always catch the Exception ...

Comment: It is for a specific purpose.

Comment: I want to use exceptions as a last resort option.

Comment: Please tag the language of your interest.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310344/why-use-when-converting-int-to-bool

Comment: @Evert What is the '!!' operator called?

Comment: Never mind I got what it meant

Comment: @sp2danny Is there a way I can use bit-manipulation or maths instead of boolean expressions?

Comment: why are you avoiding if statement?

Comment: I want to know if this problem can be solved without an if statement or without boolean expressions.

Comment: get used to using the construct that most clearly express intent, the compiler is **way** batter that mortals at micro-optimizations anyway.

Comment: @sp2danny, I understand that, but is there a way, with the conditions outlined, to solve this problem?

Comment: May I ask why this is getting heavily downvoted?

Comment: probably because the question, and eventual answers, wont be useful to someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this assumes 32bit int's

```
((static_cast<unsigned>(-(array[0]*array[0]))&(1ul<<31))>>31)
```